# Electrostatic Force, Two Spheres, and Charge by Induction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

The answer to the question below is (b) and (e).  Can anyone explain why this is so?  I'm trying to understand why one or the other sphere would have a different mass if the charge of the rod is different.  Thanks! ([source](https://demo.webassign.net/ebooks/cj6demo/pc/c18/read/main/c18x18_4.htm))

[image]

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Cool; thanks @Jonas for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the spheres exchange charge, they do this by exchanging electrons. Hence, the negatively charged sphere will have more electrons than the positively charged sphere, and should have more mass.

It's useful to note here that the mass change will be very difficult to detect in practice. The electron mass-to-charge ratio is $5.7\times 10^{-12}\,\text{kg}/\text{C}$, and $1\,\text{C}$ is quite a large amount of charge, so you'd typically expect to see a change in mass of less than a nanogram.